# Правка: "Зная и видя... становтся понятно"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите исправить ошибки в предложении или переделать его: "Зная и видя все эти старания организаторов, становится понятно и закономерно, что количество участников, начиная с первых дней соревнований и по сей день, постоянно растет".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фраза настолько корявая, что простая правка как-то не очень получается. 
Тут как минимум три ошибки надо править совместно.

Грамматическая: деепричастный оборот неверно используется:  *"Зная... становится"*.

Лексическая: "становится закономерно" - несочетаемость: как это "закономерно" становится?

Стилистическая: распространенный оборот "начиная с первых дней...." влез внутрь текста между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Первую и третью можно безболезненно поправить, а вот со второй без кардинальных изменений структуры фразы, боюсь, не совладать, да и смысл не очень понятен, что хотел автор сказать этим "становится закономерно".

Вот как-то так может быть:

***Зная и видя все эти старания организаторов, понимаешь закономерность того, что количество участников постоянно растет: начиная с первых дней соревнований и по сей день***.

Не идеально, но, возможно, в первом приближении.
Тут еще два раза "день"/"дней", но это уже - по желанию, я в том большой беды не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Видя все эти старания организаторов, начинаешь понимать,  почему количество участников, начиная с первых дней соревнований и по сей день, постоянно растет.

Comment: Вы без согласия автора пожертвовали несколькими словами, одно из  которых, возможно, ключевое - закономерность.

Comment: Слово "закономерность" можно отнести к избыточной лексике, оно только утяжеляет конструкцию, но ничего не добавляет к смыслу: "понимаешь, почему" и "понимаешь закономерность того, почему" -  по-моему, это канцелярские штампы, не более того.

Comment: Да я бы тоже отнес - в другой ситуации, но здесь без явного согласия автора не нахожу оснований для такого вмешательства. Вы домысливаете за него, а он, как нетрудно видеть, изволит изъясняться весьма вычурно, шут его знает, что для него важно...

Answer (score 0):

Зная и видя все эти старания организаторов, можно понять, почему количество участников, начиная с первых дней соревнований и по сей день, постоянно растет - это закономерно.